# how to avoid that different pages/directories in my localhost shares session?

Tags: php

I have several sites in my localhost, but when I login in one site and open other site automatically takes the username of the first site which I login.
For example, I enter localhost/site1/login.php and log in with username (user1) and pass, but when in other tab enter localhost/othersite/ and still dont login, it automatically takes  the username of the first site (user1)
How to avoid this? 
Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to resolve this by setting a session name, and then calling `session_set_cookie_params()` before starting the session on the second site:

```
$some_name = session_name("some_name");
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', 'localhost');
session_start();
```

Hope this helps! :)